# ASP.Net - Passing Variables to a Controller for Partial View

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

My goal here is to pass variables that I am keeping track of in the main view to the controller that would then be used to return the appropriate partial view.

I have attempted to use the HTTP Post attribute to pass from JQuery to the controller but receive a resource cannot be found. The thing is, i had this configured before to build the model with values inside the controller itself with no problem.I cant figure where my bug would be.

**Model**

```
namespace MapBuilder2_0.Models {
public class MapLayers {

    public bool MapLayer01 { get; set; }

    public bool MapLayer02 { get; set; }

    public bool MapLayer03 { get; set; }

    public bool MapLayer04 { get; set; }

    public bool MapLayer05 { get; set; }

    public bool MapLayer06 { get; set; }

}
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
     public PartialViewResult MapLayers(MapBuilder2_0.Models.MapLayers model) {


        return PartialView("_MapLayers", model);
    }
```

**view - Relevant Portions**

```
            <input type="hidden" id="MapLayer01" value= true />
        <input type="hidden" id="MapLayer02" value= true />
        <input type="hidden" id="MapLayer03" value= true />
        <input type="hidden" id="MapLayer04" value= true />
        <input type="hidden" id="MapLayer05" value= true />
        <input type="hidden" id="MapLayer06" value= true />

        $("#map-layers").on('click', function () {
        $.post('MapLayers', {
            MapLayer01: $('#MapLayer01').val(),
            MapLayer02: $('#MapLayer02').val(),
            MapLayer03: $('#MapLayer03').val(),
            MapLayer04: $('#MapLayer04').val(),
            MapLayer05: $('#MapLayer05').val(),
            MapLayer06: $('#MapLayer06').val()
        }).done(function (data) {
            $('#page-content-container').html(data);

        });
    });
```

**Working Controller and Jquery**

```
        public PartialViewResult MapLayers () {
        var layers = new MapBuilder2_0.Models.MapLayers() {
            MapLayer01 = true,
            MapLayer02 = true,
            MapLayer03 = true,
            MapLayer04 = true,
            MapLayer05 = true,
            MapLayer06 = true
        };

        return PartialView("_MapLayers",layers);
    }

$("#map-layers").on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $.get(this.href, function (html) {
            $('#page-content-container').html(html);
        });
    });
```

Comment: Resource could not be found typically means your route is not matching the routes in your RouteConfig.cs - Double check that your route is setup properly.

Comment: What would be the proper way to set up this post configuration. The URL format is currently set to the default of:    public class RouteConfig {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes) {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}

Comment: That is fine, but your `$.post` looks to be going to '/MapLayers' which would be the MapLayersController - Index Action (because index is the default). But really it seems like you should `$.post` to MapLayers/MapLayers

Comment: I actually have this sitting on the home controller. So going with what you suggested, I changed the $.post to Home/MapLayers. This returns that the resource cannot be found which I find quite puzzling since the MapLayers Action is clearly located int he Home Controller.

Comment: Here is some more odd behavior, but maybe you can make more sense out of it. I thought that maybe if i changed the name of the action and change the post call to reflect maybe that would eliminate some bugs. I changed the action to MapLayersView and then $.post(MapLayersView... The resource called however remained home/MapLayers... Its as if there is something configured wrong or registered improperly.

Comment: I think you need to get your head wrapped around MVC routing before trying to figure this out. There are a lot of tutorials out there, you need to understand the way routes work with controllers, actions, and views. That's beyond the scope of a SO question though.

Comment: In which folder is the Partial View _MapLayers?

Comment: Try making it an ActionResult instead of a PartialViewResult and use '/Home/MapLayers'

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is due to your controller method being typed as a `PartialViewResult`. Try changing it to an `ActionResult` like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MapLayers(MapBuilder2_0.Models.MapLayers model) {
    return PartialView("_MapLayers", model);
}
```

Comment: Still produced the resource cannot be found.

Comment: Have you tried using a breakpoint and seeing if it actually hits the POSTed method? i.e. `MapLayers`